# How to find and replace image inside <div> using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am trying to check the image and replace the image for my expand and collapse `<div>`  but i cant able to find the solution.

**html code:**

```
<h4 id="expanderHead">Virtual Room <span id="expanderSign">+</span></h4>
<div id="expanderContent" style="display:none">
    content ... content...
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
      $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
      if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
          $("#expanderSign").html("-")
      }
      else {
          $("#expanderSign").text("+")
      }
    });
});
```

Here, instead of **+** and **-** i have to place `<img src=""  alt=""/>` .

Thank you.

Comment: So what is the error you are getting? or actually what is the issue?

Comment: Just to mention but it is probably best to have the image already on the page, then just show it when you want to. This will stop the "flash" whilst the image loads when clicking the +

Comment: Also here you are checking like $("#expanderSign").text()=="+", so when the image came you need to check the whole image tag, i think it is not a good method..

Comment: @mahesh : sorry my question is how to do? Actually i tried with `attr()` and `innerHTML` but its not working.

Comment: you can use $("#expanderSign").html()..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<h4 id="expanderHead">Virtual Room <span id="expanderSign"><img src="plus-sign.png" /></span></h4>
<div id="expanderContent" style="display:none">
    content ... content...
</div>​
```

### EDITED (Added better jQuery Version)

**jQuery New Version**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#expanderHead").click(function(){

       $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();

       var plusImg = "http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/16/129.png";
       var minusImg = "http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/16/130.png";        
       $this = $("#expanderSign img");            

       if( $this.attr('src') == plusImg ) { $this.attr('src', minusImg);} 
       else { $this.attr('src', plusImg); }

   });
});
```

### [**SEE LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/85ywP/)

Comment: @Ran: Updated my answer with a better jQuery implementation. Discard the old suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
      $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
      if ($("#imgId").attr('src') == "d2.png"){
          $("#imgId").attr("src","d1.png")
      }
      else {
          $("#imgId").attr("src","d2.png")
      }
    });
});

    <h4 id="expanderHead">Virtual Room <img id='imgId' src='d2.png' /></h4>
<div id="expanderContent" style="display:none">
    content ... content...
</div>
```